# Unity loadConfiguration failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

I have the following unity construct method:

```
public static IUnityContainer CreateContainer()
{
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.LoadConfiguration();

    .......
}
```

Then an interface, and an implementation class:

```
namespace MyCompany.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common
{
    public interface ISession
    {
    }
}

namespace MyCompany.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common
{
    public class SessionHandler : ISession
    {
    }
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
Container.RegisterType<ISession, SessionHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()) ;
```

I want to use container.LoadConfiguration() to load the above RegisterType config from the web.config. **BUT it doesn't seem to work**

web.config:

```
  <unity>
    <containers>
      <container>
        <types>

          <type type="MyCompany.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common.ISession" mapTo="MyCompany.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common.SessionHandler">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </type>
        </types>
      </container>
    </containers>
  </unity>
```

**Exception:**

The type name or alias MyProject.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common.ISession could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The type name or alias MyProject.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common.ISession could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

**Source Error:**

Line 33:         {
Line 34:             UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
Line 35:             container.LoadConfiguration();
Line 36: 
Line 37:            //container.RegisterType(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

**Stack Trace:**

> [InvalidOperationException: The type name or alias MyProject.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common.ISession could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.]
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.TypeResolverImpl.ResolveType(String typeNameOrAlias, Boolean throwIfResolveFails) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\ConfigurationHelpers\TypeResolverImpl.cs:110
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.TypeResolver.ResolveType(String typeNameOrAlias) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\ConfigurationHelpers\TypeResolver.cs:47
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.GetRegisteringType() in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\RegisterElement.cs:121
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.RegisterElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\RegisterElement.cs:88
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerConfiguringElement.ConfigureContainerInternal(IUnityContainer container) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\ContainerConfiguringElement.cs:43
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(ContainerConfiguringElement element) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\ContainerElement.cs:114
>      Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach(IEnumerable`1 sequence, Action`1 action) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Utility\EnumerableExtensions.cs:36
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\ContainerElement.cs:110
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection.Configure(IUnityContainer container, String configuredContainerName) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\UnityConfigurationSection.cs:151
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IUnityContainer container, UnityConfigurationSection section, String containerName) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\UnityContainerExtensions.cs:37
>      Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IUnityContainer container) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity.Configuration\Src\UnityContainerExtensions.cs:64
>      MyProject.Web.ApplicationContainer.CreateContainer() in C:\Workspace\MCDev\MyApp\MyApp\MyProject.Web\ApplicationContainer.cs:35
>      MyProject.Web.ApplicationContainer.Initialize(HttpContext context) in C:\Workspace\MCDev\MyApp\MyApp\MyProject.Web\ApplicationContainer.cs:53
>      MyProject.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Workspace\MCDev\MyApp\MyApp\MyProject.Web\Global.asax.cs:41

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it knows what dll to look in:

```
<unity>
    <containers>
      <container>
        <types>
          <type type="MyCompany.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common.ISession, MyCompany" mapTo="MyCompany.Web.Areas.MyApp.Common.SessionHandler, MyCompany">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </type>
        </types>
      </container>
    </containers>
  </unity>
```

Comment: Keep in mind, requiring the assembly name is exactly how lookup by name in .NET works (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whether you are using Unity or not.